# How do I change the color of scatter plot points (with a changing data set)? -- Google Apps Script -- SpreadSheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been having trouble changing the color of my scatter plot points. Here's what it looks like now:

[Current Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay5r8.png)

I'm trying to set series B28:B60 to be red, and C28:C60 to be green (to indicate departure/arrival). I can't seem to get it though..

Here is my code now:

Here is the solved question:

```js
function doGet(n) {
  Logger.log("--- doGet ---");
  var name = "",
    status = "";
  try {
    if (n == null) { n = {}; n.parameters = { name: "test", status: "-1" }; }
    name = n.parameters.name;
    status = n.parameters.status;
    save_data(name, status);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Wrote:\n  name: " + name + "\n  status: " + status);
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("oops...." + error.message
      + "\n" + new Date()
      + "\nname: " + name +
      + "\nstatus: " + status);
  }
}

function addNewSheetForToday() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var date = new Date();
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MM-dd-yyyy");
  var existingSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(formattedDate);
  if (existingSheet) {
    Logger.log("Sheet for today already exists.");
    return;
  }
  var newSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1").copyTo(spreadsheet).setName(formattedDate);
  newSheet.getCharts().forEach(c => newSheet.removeChart(c));
  createScatterPlot(newSheet);
  var numRows = 60;
  var numColumns = 15;
  var colors = ['#BBBBBB', '#CCCCCC'];
  for (var c = 28; c <= numRows; c++) {
    var colorIndex = (c - 2) % colors.length;
    var row = newSheet.getRange(c, 1, 1, numColumns);
    row.setBackground(colors[colorIndex]);
  }
  var headerRow = newSheet.getRange(27, 2, 1, numColumns);
  headerRow.setFontStyle("italic");
  var headerColumn = newSheet.getRange(28, 1, numRows, 1);
  headerColumn.setFontWeight("bold");
}

function createScatterPlot(newSheet) {
  Logger.log("--- createScatterPlot ---");
  var title = "Today's Timestamps";
  var titleFontSize = 18;
  var titleRow = 1;
  var titleColumn = 6;
  var titleCell = newSheet.getRange(titleRow, titleColumn);
  titleCell.setValue(title)
    .setFontWeight("bold")
    .setFontSize(titleFontSize)
    .setHorizontalAlignment("right");

  var range1 = newSheet.getRange('A28:B60');
  var range2 = newSheet.getRange('C28:O60');
  var chartBuilder = newSheet.newChart()
    .asScatterChart()
    .setXAxisTitle('Student')
    .setYAxisTitle('Time')
    .addRange(range1)
    .addRange(range2)
    .setPosition(2, 1, 0, 0)
    .setOption('width', 960)
    .setOption('height', 480)
    .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
    .setColors(["red", ...Array(range2.getNumColumns()).fill("green")])
    .build();
  newSheet.insertChart(chartBuilder);
}

function onEdit(e) {
  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const charts = sheet.getCharts();
  if (range.rowStart < 28 || range.rowEnd > 60 || range.columnStart == 1 || range.columnStart > 15 || charts.length == 0) return;
  const range2 = sheet.getRange('C28:O60');
  const chart = charts[0].modify().asScatterChart().setColors(["red", ...Array(range2.getNumColumns()).fill("green")]).build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
}

function save_data(name, status) {
  Logger.log("--- save_data ---");
  try {
    addNewSheetForToday();
    var today = new Date();
    var time = Utilities.formatDate(today, "GMT-4", "hh:mm");
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("putyourURLhere");
    var dataLoggerSheet = ss.getSheetByName(Utilities.formatDate(today, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MM-dd-yyyy"));
    var studentnames = ["", "Alep", "Bet", "Gamal", "Dalat", "Heh", "Waw", "Zen", "Khet", "Tet", "Yod", "Kap", "Lamad", "Meem", "Noon", "Simkat", "Eh", "Peh", "Sahdeh", "Qope", "Resh", "Sheen", "Tao", "Martin", "Allyson", "Ashur", "Matilda", "Odin", "Ophelia", "Brownie", "Oreo", "SubCard1", "SubCard2", "SubCard3"];
    for (var i = 0; i < studentnames.length; i++) {
      dataLoggerSheet.getRange("A" + (i + 27)).setValue(studentnames[i]);
    }
    if (name == "Alep") {
      if (dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C28").getValue() == "" || dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C28").getValue() == null) {
        dataLoggerSheet.getRange("B27").setValue("1st Departure");
        dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C27").setValue("1st Return");
        if (status == "Departed") {
          dataLoggerSheet.getRange("B28").setValue(time);
        } else if (status == "Returned") {
          dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C28").setValue(time);
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
  Logger.log("--- save_data end---");
```

Comment: When I saw your showing script, it seems that my previous modification is not reflected, and also as I mentioned in my comment in your previous question, `var newSheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(formattedDate);` is not modified to `var newSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1").copyTo(spreadsheet).setName(formattedDate)` in `addNewSheetForToday()`. How about them? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the newSheet variable. It is correctly going to the sheet that I want it to go to. The data set is being modified correctly, I just can't change the color. I did try the modification but I couldn't get it to work with my existing code.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I did try the modification but I couldn't get it to work with my existing code.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? And, your showing script is the script of `but I couldn't get it to work with my existing code.`? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: It's no problem. Thank you for being patient with me. I know that the function that you sent me works by itself. But, when I try to use it with my code, it doesn't work. I don't know why. I saw something like this "var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
chart = chart.modify()
    .setOption('series.1.color', 'red')
    .setOption('series.2.color', 'green')
    .build();
sheet.updateChart(chart);" as a possible answer? Maybe it should be as chart.modify()?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question and reply, I proposed a modified script. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and reply, I apologize. At that time, can you provide your sample Spreadsheet including my proposed script? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your reply, I thought that I might misunderstand your expected result. I guessed your expected result is as follows.

- First, you run your current showing script. By this, a new sheet is inserted including a chart. In this case, no values are existing in the cells "B28:O60".
- When you put a value to the cells "B28:O60", you want to set the colors of dots in the chart.

  - "B28:B60" is red.
  - "C28:O60" is green.

If my understanding is correct, in this case, I thought that it might be required to update the chart when the value is put to the cells "B28:O60". Because it seems that when no values are existing, the dot colors cannot be set. If my understanding of this situation is correct, please use the following sample script.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of your provided Spreadsheet and save the script.

**This script is automatically run when the cell is edited. Please don't directly run this function.**

When you test this, please put a value to the cells "B28:O60". By this, the script is automatically run with the OnEdit trigger.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const charts = sheet.getCharts();
  if (range.rowStart < 28 || range.rowEnd > 60 || range.columnStart == 1 || range.columnStart > 15 || charts.length == 0) return;
  const range2 = sheet.getRange('C28:O60');
  const chart = charts[0].modify().asScatterChart().setColors(["red", ...Array(range2.getNumColumns()).fill("green")]).build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
}
```

### Added 1:

From your following reply,

> HOWEVER TO MAKE THINGS EVEN MORE COMPLICATED... I'm logging data not directly through google sheets. I'm logging data through an external device that is connected via WiFi. It seems that this only changes the colors if I directly type in numbers on the sheets, but not when it is logged via the device. Hahahah at this point I think I'll just keep it with the standard colors...

Although, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation, in this case, I guess that the cell might be updated by Sheets API. If my understanding is correct, please test the following script.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet, and save the script.

And also, [please install OnChange trigger to `onChange` function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). By this, when the cell is updated by Sheets API, this script is automatically run by the OnChange trigger.

```js
function onChange(e) {
  const { source, changeType } = e;
  const sheet = source.getActiveSheet();
  const charts = sheet.getCharts();
  if (changeType != "EDIT" || charts.length == 0) return;
  const range2 = sheet.getRange('C28:O60');
  const chart = charts[0].modify().asScatterChart().setColors(["red", ...Array(range2.getNumColumns()).fill("green")]).build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
}
```

### Added 2:

From your following reply,

> I tried this and it doesn't seem to work. Data is being sent via an ESP32 that is connected to WiFi using the Google ID String. Again, it works perfectly fine if I do type in the numbers, just not when I log the numbers through the device.

In this case, I guessed that the cell might be updated by Web Apps. In this case, I think that the following 2 solution patterns can be considered.

1. Using the above `onChange` of "Added1", modify the script for putting the value using Sheets API. In this case, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services.

   - If `dataLoggerSheet.getRange("B28").setValue(time);` is modified, it's `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({values: [[time]]}, "###Spreadsheet ID###", "'07-21-2023'!B28", {valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"});`.
   - If `ataLoggerSheet.getRange("C28").setValue(time);` is modified, it's `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({values: [[time]]}, "###Spreadsheet ID###", "'07-21-2023'!C28", {valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"});`.
2. Directly updating the chart. The simple sample script is as follows. For example, please put this function after the value was put in your showing script.

   ```js
   function sample() {
     const sheetName = "07-21-2023"; // Please set your sheet name.

     const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // or SpreadsheetApp.openById("###Spreadsheet ID###") or SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("### spreadsheet URL ###")
     const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
     const charts = sheet.getCharts();
     if (charts.length == 0) return;
     const range2 = sheet.getRange('C28:O60');
     const chart = charts[0].modify().asScatterChart().setColors(["red", ...Array(range2.getNumColumns()).fill("green")]).build();
     sheet.updateChart(chart);
   }
   ```

### Added 3:

From your following reply,

> Okay, I'm trying to do the function sample() but I don't know where I should put it into my code

How about putting the function `save_data` as follows?

```js
if (name == "Alep") {
  if (dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C28").getValue() == "" || dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C28").getValue() == null) {
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("B27").setValue("1st Departure");
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C27").setValue("1st Return");
    if (status == "Departed") {
      dataLoggerSheet.getRange("B28").setValue(time);
    } else if (status == "Returned") {
      dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C28").setValue(time);
    }

    // --- Added
    const charts = dataLoggerSheet.getCharts();
    if (charts.length == 0) return;
    const range2 = dataLoggerSheet.getRange('C28:O60');
    const chart = charts[0].modify().asScatterChart().setColors(["red", ...Array(range2.getNumColumns()).fill("green")]).build();
    dataLoggerSheet.updateChart(chart);
    // ---

  }
}
```

or

```js
if (name == "Alep") {
  if (dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C28").getValue() == "" || dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C28").getValue() == null) {
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("B27").setValue("1st Departure");
    dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C27").setValue("1st Return");
    if (status == "Departed") {
      dataLoggerSheet.getRange("B28").setValue(time);
    } else if (status == "Returned") {
      dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C28").setValue(time);
    }

    // --- Added
    sample(); // In this case, before you run the script, please set the sheet name in sample().
    // ---

  }
}
```

- When you modify the script, please reflect the latest script to Web Apps. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I tried this on a separate Spreadsheet, to no avail: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jekdkBVGJju-gmjtsZpUYbST9m0ujzl6tJoQthDB6Rs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @ScythaScytha Thank you for replying. From your reply, I thought that I might misunderstand your expected result. So, I updated my answer by guessing your situation and the expected result. Please confirm it. If I still misunderstood your question, I apologize, again.

Comment: This answered my question!!! HOWEVER TO MAKE THINGS EVEN MORE COMPLICATED... I'm logging data not directly through google sheets. I'm logging data through an external device that is connected via WiFi. It seems that this only changes the colors if I directly type in numbers on the sheets, but not when it is logged via the device. Hahahah at this point I think I'll just keep it with the standard colors... Thanks so much anyway

Comment: @ScythaScytha Thank you for replying. I'm glad your this question was resolved. About your new issue of `HOWEVER TO MAKE THINGS EVEN MORE COMPLICATED...`, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it. But, I'm not sure about your actual situation. So, when this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to work. Data is being sent via an ESP32 that is connected to WiFi using the Google ID String. Again, it works perfectly fine if I do type in the numbers, just not when I log the numbers through the device.

Comment: Here's a video of me using it: https://photos.app.goo.gl/BwcaNCscvssmUMqJ8

Comment: @ScythaScytha Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't notice `Data is being sent via an ESP32 that is connected to WiFi using the Google ID String.` from your question. So, I updated my answer. Please confirm it. When that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: Okay, I'm trying to do the function sample() but I don't know where I should put it into my code

Comment: @ScythaScytha Thank you for replying. About `Okay, I'm trying to do the function sample() but I don't know where I should put it into my code`, I apologize for my poor English skill. For example, how about putting it after the value was put in your showing script? In your script, the value is put using `setValue(time)`? But, before you run the script, please set the sheet name.

Comment: No I apologize for my poor programming skills! Your English is perfect

Comment: @ScythaScytha I updated my answer for `Okay, I'm trying to do the function sample() but I don't know where I should put it into my code`. Please confirm it.

Comment: Sorry Tanaike I just cant get it to work. I tried it in a few different configurations and its still not updating the colors.

Comment: @ScythaScytha Thank you for replying. About `Sorry Tanaike I just cant get it to work. I tried it in a few different configurations and its still not updating the colors.`, I'm worried that you might have been not correctly using my proposed script and setting. I think that the reason for this is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. But, I would like to support you.

Comment: @ScythaScytha So, can you post it as a new question by including more information for correctly replicating `its still not updating the colors`? Because your this question has already been resolved. By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @ScythaScytha By the way, when I tested the modified script reflected my proposed script using a sample event object, I can confirm that the script works and the colors of dots are changed. I apologize for this situation. By the way, how about reflecting the latest script to Web Apps again and test it again?

Comment: I posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76736322/trying-to-change-my-scatter-plot-dot-color-using-an-esp32-google-apps-script Maybe you can tell me what I'm doing wrong?