# Trying to change my scatter plot dot color using an ESP32 - Google - Apps Script/Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is the updated code now:

```js
function doGet(n) {
  Logger.log("--- doGet ---");
  var name = "",
    status = "";
  try {
    if (n == null) { n = {}; n.parameters = { name: "test", status: "-1" }; }
    name = n.parameters.name;
    status = n.parameters.status;
    save_data(name, status);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Wrote:\n  name: " + name + "\n  status: " + status);
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("oops...." + error.message
      + "\n" + new Date()
      + "\nname: " + name +
      + "\nstatus: " + status);
  }
}

function addNewSheetForToday() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var date = new Date();
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MM-dd-yyyy");
  var existingSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(formattedDate);
  if (existingSheet) {
    Logger.log("Sheet for today already exists.");
    return;
  }
  var newSheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(formattedDate);
  newSheet.getCharts().forEach(c => newSheet.removeChart(c));
  createScatterPlot(newSheet);
  var numRows = 60;
  var numColumns = 15;
  var colors = ['#BBBBBB', '#CCCCCC'];
  for (var c = 28; c <= numRows; c++) {
    var colorIndex = (c - 2) % colors.length;
    var row = newSheet.getRange(c, 1, 1, numColumns);
    row.setBackground(colors[colorIndex]);
  }
  var headerRow = newSheet.getRange(27, 2, 1, numColumns);
  headerRow.setFontStyle("italic");
  var headerColumn = newSheet.getRange(28, 1, numRows, 1);
  headerColumn.setFontWeight("bold");
}

function createScatterPlot(newSheet) {
  Logger.log("--- createScatterPlot ---");
  var title = "Today's Timestamps";
  var titleFontSize = 18;
  var titleRow = 1;
  var titleColumn = 6;
  var titleCell = newSheet.getRange(titleRow, titleColumn);
  titleCell.setValue(title)
    .setFontWeight("bold")
    .setFontSize(titleFontSize)
    .setHorizontalAlignment("right");
  var range1 = newSheet.getRange('A28:B60');
  var range2 = newSheet.getRange('C28:O60');
  var chartBuilder = newSheet.newChart()
    .asScatterChart()
    .addRange(range1)
    .addRange(range2)
    .setPosition(2, 1, 0, 0)
    .setOption('width', 960)
    .setOption('height', 480)
    .build();
  newSheet.insertChart(chartBuilder);
}

function sample() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jekdkBVGJju-gmjtsZpUYbST9m0ujzl6tJoQthDB6Rs/edit#gid=0");
  const sheetName = ss.getSheetByName(Utilities.formatDate(today, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MM-dd-yyyy"));
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const charts = sheet.getCharts();
  if (charts.length == 0) return;
  const range2 = sheet.getRange('C28:O60');
  const chart = charts[0].modify().asScatterChart().setColors(["red", ...Array(range2.getNumColumns()).fill("green")]).build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
}

function save_data(name, status) {
  Logger.log("--- save_data ---");
  try {
    addNewSheetForToday();
    var today = new Date();
    var time = Utilities.formatDate(today, "GMT-4", "hh:mm");
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jekdkBVGJju-gmjtsZpUYbST9m0ujzl6tJoQthDB6Rs/edit#gid=0");
    var dataLoggerSheet = ss.getSheetByName(Utilities.formatDate(today, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MM-dd-yyyy"));
    var studentnames = ["", "Alep", "Bet", "Gamal", "Dalat", "Heh", "Waw", "Zen", "Khet", "Tet", "Yod", "Kap", "Lamad", "Meem", "Noon", "Simkat", "Eh", "Peh", "Sahdeh", "Qope", "Resh", "Sheen", "Tao", "Martin", "Allyson", "Ashur", "Matilda", "Odin", "Ophelia", "Brownie", "Oreo", "SubCard1", "SubCard2", "SubCard3"];
    for (var i = 0; i < studentnames.length; i++) {
      dataLoggerSheet.getRange("A" + (i + 27)).setValue(studentnames[i]);
    }
    if (name == "Alep") {
      if (dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C28").getValue() == "" || dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C28").getValue() == null) {
        dataLoggerSheet.getRange("B27").setValue("1st Departure");
        dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C27").setValue("1st Return");
        if (status == "Departed") {
          dataLoggerSheet.getRange("B28").setValue(time);
        } else if (status == "Returned") {
          dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C28").setValue(time);
        }
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        sample();
      }
  }
}
  catch (error) {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
  Logger.log("--- save_data end---");
}
```

I did change the URLs to be the same. Unfortunately that wasn't the cause of the issue. I just inverted them (one was for testing and the other was to keep).

I am not seeing any color change at all even when I am manually editing them. Should I have kept one the triggers on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are actually using your showing script, I think that the script is required to be modified. Please modify `sample` and `save_data` as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
// Modified
function sample() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jekdkBVGJju-gmjtsZpUYbST9m0ujzl6tJoQthDB6Rs/edit#gid=0");
  const sheetName = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MM-dd-yyyy");
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const charts = sheet.getCharts();
  if (charts.length == 0) return;
  const range2 = sheet.getRange('C28:O60');
  const chart = charts[0].modify().asScatterChart().setColors(["red", ...Array(range2.getNumColumns()).fill("green")]).build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
}

function save_data(name, status) {
  Logger.log("--- save_data ---");
  try {
    addNewSheetForToday();
    var today = new Date();
    var time = Utilities.formatDate(today, "GMT-4", "hh:mm");
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jekdkBVGJju-gmjtsZpUYbST9m0ujzl6tJoQthDB6Rs/edit#gid=0");
    var dataLoggerSheet = ss.getSheetByName(Utilities.formatDate(today, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MM-dd-yyyy"));
    var studentnames = ["", "Alep", "Bet", "Gamal", "Dalat", "Heh", "Waw", "Zen", "Khet", "Tet", "Yod", "Kap", "Lamad", "Meem", "Noon", "Simkat", "Eh", "Peh", "Sahdeh", "Qope", "Resh", "Sheen", "Tao", "Martin", "Allyson", "Ashur", "Matilda", "Odin", "Ophelia", "Brownie", "Oreo", "SubCard1", "SubCard2", "SubCard3"];
    for (var i = 0; i < studentnames.length; i++) {
      dataLoggerSheet.getRange("A" + (i + 27)).setValue(studentnames[i]);
    }
    if (name == "Alep") {
      if (dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C28").getValue() == "" || dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C28").getValue() == null) {
        dataLoggerSheet.getRange("B27").setValue("1st Departure");
        dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C27").setValue("1st Return");
        if (status == "Departed") {
          dataLoggerSheet.getRange("B28").setValue(time);
        } else if (status == "Returned") {
          dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C28").setValue(time);
        }
        SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // This might be required to be used.
        sample();
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
  Logger.log("--- save_data end---");
}
```

or, how about the following modification?

```js
function save_data(name, status) {
  Logger.log("--- save_data ---");
  try {
    addNewSheetForToday();
    var today = new Date();
    var time = Utilities.formatDate(today, "GMT-4", "hh:mm");
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jekdkBVGJju-gmjtsZpUYbST9m0ujzl6tJoQthDB6Rs/edit#gid=0");
    var dataLoggerSheet = ss.getSheetByName(Utilities.formatDate(today, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MM-dd-yyyy"));
    var studentnames = ["", "Alep", "Bet", "Gamal", "Dalat", "Heh", "Waw", "Zen", "Khet", "Tet", "Yod", "Kap", "Lamad", "Meem", "Noon", "Simkat", "Eh", "Peh", "Sahdeh", "Qope", "Resh", "Sheen", "Tao", "Martin", "Allyson", "Ashur", "Matilda", "Odin", "Ophelia", "Brownie", "Oreo", "SubCard1", "SubCard2", "SubCard3"];
    for (var i = 0; i < studentnames.length; i++) {
      dataLoggerSheet.getRange("A" + (i + 27)).setValue(studentnames[i]);
    }
    if (name == "Alep") {
      if (dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C28").getValue() == "" || dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C28").getValue() == null) {
        dataLoggerSheet.getRange("B27").setValue("1st Departure");
        dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C27").setValue("1st Return");
        if (status == "Departed") {
          dataLoggerSheet.getRange("B28").setValue(time);
        } else if (status == "Returned") {
          dataLoggerSheet.getRange("C28").setValue(time);
        }

        // --- Modified
        SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // This might be required to be used.
        const charts = dataLoggerSheet.getCharts();
        if (charts.length == 0) return;
        const range2 = dataLoggerSheet.getRange('C28:O60');
        const chart = charts[0].modify().asScatterChart().setColors(["red", ...Array(range2.getNumColumns()).fill("green")]).build();
        dataLoggerSheet.updateChart(chart);
        // --- 

      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
  Logger.log("--- save_data end---");
}
```

Comment: @ScythaScytha Now, I noticed that in your script, it seems that the Spreadsheet ID in the functions `sample()` and `save_data` are different. `sample()` update the chart of the Spreadsheet that the value is put. So, in this case, `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zGqyFVq-1PtPixh8ZW_BfgqXoja2nCJ8zPhdnixVJQ4/edit#gid=0` is required to be also used in `sample()`? But, I cannot know your actual situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: I updated the question. No that was just an error in copying. I had 2 URLs open. Unfortunately it's still not updating properly.

Comment: @ScythaScytha Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor skill. Now, I noticed that in your script of `sample`, `today` is not declared, and `sheetName` is not sheet name, it's a Class Sheet object. So, I updated my answer. Please confirm it. By the way, from `I updated the question. No that was just an error in copying. I had 2 URLs open. Unfortunately it's still not updating properly.`, I think that my 2nd pattern can be also used.